# Disabling asp validators using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator, customvalidator

In a webform, I have a checkbox and 3 textboxes. I added required field validators to all the 3 textboxes. I want textbox1 to be mandatory only when the checkbox is checked. I want to do it using javascript. I am using customvalidator and I am not sure where I am doing mistake. Below is my code.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:CheckBox Checked="false" ID="chkBox"  runat="server"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" Enabled="true" runat="server" />
    <asp:CustomValidator id="newcstvalid" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxValidation"></asp:CustomValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvchkbox" ControlToValidate="txtBox1" ErrorMessage="error" ValidationGroup="abc"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvtxt1" ControlToValidate="txtBox2" ErrorMessage="error" ValidationGroup="abc"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtBox3" ErrorMessage="error" ValidationGroup="abc"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />

    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Button" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="abc"/>
    <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="valsumm" ValidationGroup="abc" ShowValidationErrors="true" />
</div>
</form>
```

my javascript function is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckBoxValidation() {
        var myCheckBox = document.getElementById("<%= chkBox.ClientID %>");            
        var validator = document.getElementById("<%= rfvchkbox.ClientID %>");
        if (myCheckBox.checked)
        { ValidatorEnable(validator, true); }
        else { ValidatorEnable(validator, false); }                
        }        
</script>
```

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple validators to accomplish what you're attempting, here.  First, get rid of the requiredfieldvalidator "rfvchkbox" - you don't need it.

Second, your CustomValidator is missing a few things, notably ControlToValidate.

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="newcstvalid" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxValidation" ControlToValidate="txtBox1" ErrorMessage="* Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Next, instead of enabling/disabling a separate control, your function should be setting the args.isValid property to true or false.

```
function CheckBoxValidation(source, args) {
        if ($("<%=chkBox.ClientID%>").checked && args.toString().length == 0)
            args.IsValid = false;
        else
            args.IsValid = true; 
        }
```

Check out the msdn documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx

I would also suggest a more descriptive error message for your validators than "Error"